# How to show SL and Target in plotshape text?

Tags: pine-script

[image]I looked around the blogs and found the answer that to show SL and Target in plotshape is not possible and need to use lable.new.

```
var label l = na
if validLong
    l := label.new(bar_index, high, text="SL  = (" + str.tostring(stop_diff) + ")" + " | Tgt = "+str.tostring(profit_diff),textcolor=color.white)
```

I tried changing it from plotshape to lable.new. Now got a new issue that is when I go back in previous months with Bar-reply I could see plotshape of buy signals but labels are disappeared. Any fix ?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to number of labels you can display on your chart. The default value is 50. You can increase this with `max_labels_count` argument if you haven't already. Max value is 500.

Add `max_labels_count=500` to your `strategy()` or `indicator()` call.